# Gson - deserialize unknown classes

Tags: java, json, gson

Lets say I have a group of classes A,B,C:

public class A:
int number;

public class B:
int number;
String address;

public class C:
int orderNumber;

How can i deserialize a Json string which contains only these classes, but in an unknown order (using Gson, in Java)? For example:

```
{//A
"number" : 3
}
//C
{
"orderNumber": 10
}
//B
{
"number" : 5
"address" : "New York"
}
//C
{
"orderNumber": 1
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should first convert the json payload into a general structure(like JsonNode in Jackson) and then decide which class you want to cast it to.

Comment: You can deserialize json as hashmap

Answer (score 1):

Answer by pirho is clean and easy if, like he said, your classes are simple as you've provided. But if that isn't the case, you can write your own deserializer.

```
public class PayloadJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement elm, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // create java objects based on the properties in the json object
        JsonPrimitive orderNumber = elm.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("orderNumber");
        if(!orderNumber.isJsonNull()) {
            return new C(orderNumber.getAsInt());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Register your custom deserializer with Gson.

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder()
                    .registerTypeAdapter(PayloadJson.class, new PayloadJsonDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```

Use it to deserialize your json.

```
gson.fromJson(jsonString, PayloadJson[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a generic or anyway a great strategy to do this in general if you have more complex classes with more fields.

But if the classes you want to deserialize are as simple as you provide as an example then create a class having all these fields

```
@Getter
public class Z {
   private Integer orderNumber;
   private Integer number;
   private String address;
}
```

You will get a list of `Z`s and depending on which of the field are `null` or not `null` you can -if needed - later construct `A`, `B` or `C` from `Z`.

If classes to deserialize are more complex you anyway need to create some kind of a mechanism that determines what is the class to parse and to return. It could  be like **user1516873** suggested in the comment

```
Collection<Map<String,String>>
```

so for each item you would need to determine by what fields are present in that map to what class - `A`,`B` or `C` - item would be constructed.